# How to convert object to interface which is fetched by axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a homework to use 
https://exchangeratesapi.io/
 for currency supports, I have fetched the data with axios and it prints the object in console log. I want to get "rates" field especially in `CAD`, I have no more idea how to do it. Thank you for helping

I tried to access the value by this.state.data.rates but it was error, by using `((this.state.data as any).rates as any).CAD &  ((this.state.data as any).rates as any)["CAD"]` but they were also error.
It is said that my type is never. I cast it to any, and it showed nothing.
I tried to Convert the `JSON` to interface, but I don't know how to use it in `IState`.

I can get Value of date and base by using ((this.state.data as any).date

```
/*It is my interface*/

interface IState {
    data?: object | null;
    isCurrency?: boolean;
    Currency?: string;
    Rate?: number;
}


/*It is inside class { */

state = {
    isCurrency: false,
    Currency: "USD",
    Rate: 1,
    data: [] = []
};

async componentWillMount() {
    let result = await this.service.getAllCurrency();
    this.setState({
      data: (result as Pick<IState, keyof IState>).data
    });
}

/*I want to render*/
<h1>{((this.state.data as any).rates as any)["CAD"]} Kd</h1>

<h1>{((this.state.data as any).rates as any).CAD} Kd</h1>
```

**The output is 1.4627 (latest data from API)**

Comment: can you provide the output the console gives when you print the axios data object? is that the `result` you talk about in `componentWillMount()` ?

Comment: yes, it is the result in componentWillMount()

the result is object there are config, data, etc
inside data -> base, date, rates
inside rates -> all the currencies